# Create library for Android development?

Tags: android, package, adt

I'm pretty new to Android development, but I  have some experience with Java and Eclipse. I'm looking for ways to create re-usable libraries (controls, helpers, "standard" activities, etc.) that I could use in my own projects, but that could also be distributed to other developers without disclosing the source code.

Normally, I'd package the class files into a JAR file and any other developer could add it to the classpath and use the packaged classes.

How can I do that with Android projects? I've read about Android Library Projects, but as the documentation states they can not be packaged into a JAR, but will be compiled along with the project that references the library project. This means I also have to distribute the source code.

I've also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252552/differences-between-jar-android-library-and-android-library-project), which asks about the same question but didn't provide a satisfying answer.

So: Is there a way of compiling and packaging a set of classes and other files (including XML layouts, resources and stuff) and distribute only that package without any source codes so that it can be "referenced" and used like a JAR file by any other developer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've read about Android Library Projects, but as the documentation states they can not be
>   packaged into a JAR, but will be compiled along with the project that references the library
>   project. This means I also have to distribute the source code.

Not true. It does require a bit of extra packaging work, but you can compile your code to a JAR and distribute the JAR in the library project's `libs/` directory.

> So: Is there a way of compiling and packaging a set of classes and other files (including
>   XML layouts, resources and stuff) and distribute only that package without any source
>   codes so that it can be "referenced" and used like a JAR file by any other developer?

Use an Android library project. I have [some stuff written up here](http://andparcel.com/) that describes a bit more of the packaging options, plus pointers to some "parcels" that follow the conventions described therein.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I'm looking for. Even though I only gave it a quick read, I'll mark your answer as accepted answer, because it seems to actually get me somewhere :-)

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: Please feel free to send me feedback on problems you encounter, through the `cw-android` Google Group. This is a fairly recent (and hasty) rewrite of this material to adopt library projects as the foundation, and I am sure I need to add more information here.

Comment: @CommonsWare it appears the link you referenced is no longer working. Is there any other place we can find this information? If it's not too much info, it may be beneficial to post some of it here.

Comment: @MattWolfe: Try the Reusable Components chapter of http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/AdvAndroid-1_9-CC.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for your solution. From what I understand, you still can not access the resources private to the library from within the libary code. So assume your library has a string resource named "my_lib_resource" under res/values in the library. You bundle this in the jar along with the source code. Can you access this resource from the library source code using something like:

```
int id = res.getIdentifier("com.example.mylib:string/my_lib_resource",null,null)
```

assuming your library package name is com.example.mylib.

For me this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Brave new world of dependency management:

http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects