# Create an Android project that doesn't have AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

I am new to android...and i am trying to build an application that doesn't have AndroidManifest.xml but does contains files like .sh,.bat,.exe,etc. Along with folders ant-lib and lib containing .jar files...

Please help me as to how should i build such an android project from scratch

Please help

Comment: Why you don't want the manifest?

Comment: What exactly do you expect your project to be able to do?

Comment: Actually I do want the other files which i mentioned. I am trying to build something similar to DataExtractionOSM of osmand. So how do i build such a project from scratch. Please help.....

Comment: @everybody

I am trying to build something similar to http://code.google.com/p/osmand/source/browse/#hg%2FDataExtractionOSM%2Fant-lib%253Fstate%253Dclosed  so somebody please help.........

Comment: Yes correct but please see http://code.google.com/p/osmand/source/browse/#hg%2FDataExtractionOSM%2Fant-lib%253Fstate%253Dclosed to DataExtractionOSM its build like that only...

Comment: Osmand does have a AndroidMannifest.xml. But osmand is made of sub-projects..see this groups.google.com/group/osmand/browse_thread/thread/… in the post by Pavol it is mentioned that DataExtractionOSM and OsmAnd projects are projects and i am asking that how would we create DataExtraction project from scratch.

Comment: @user687026: Sorry buddy, I didn't saw the DataExtractor project. What I looked at is the main OsmAnd project. You should better contact the authors of project to know about the issue. I'm deleting my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvious question: Why do you want to create an app without an AndroidManifest.xml? It's like creating a Java application without a main-method.
Maybe it helps if you give more details on what you're trying to do. For example, why do you want to include .bat and .exe files in your application? Remember that Android is based on a Linux plattform so I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here..

Comment: Please see above..i am trying to build an application which is something like osmand

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to Android do the following:

- Read the application fundamentals: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html
- Create a Hello World app: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html
- Browse the API Demos application and learn from the code: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html

Having an Android app without a manifest.xml file is totally nonsense. This is how Android works. It needs the manifest to be able to understand what kind of permission your app has, what kind of [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) (UI) it provides etc... You basically **cannot** have an application without an manifest file.

Comment: Respected Sir...with utmost respect i state the i have already read the basics..and hav build a few simple apps..like using GPS and for weather etc...i am trying to move towards something tough...so please help me...my idea is similar to osmand. Its not nonesense Sir you may see http://code.google.com/p/osmand/source/browse/#hg%2FDataExtractionOSM%2Fant-lib%253Fstate%253Dclosed its build like that. And in my app i want to build something similar. So please help...

Comment: I repeat. Android apps need to have a Manifest.xml file, otherwise the system won't understand your app, nor will you be able to register it. How would Google otherwise be able to detect device compatibility and to handle security issues?? The project OSMAND you mention has a manifest.xml as well: http://code.google.com/p/osmand/source/browse/#hg%2FOsmAnd

Comment: Osmand does have a AndroidMannifest.xml. But osmand is made of sub-projects..see this http://groups.google.com/group/osmand/browse_thread/thread/7097a38130e3b014?fwc=1  in the post by Pavol it is mentioned that DataExtractionOSM and OsmAnd projects are projects and i am asking that how would we create DataExtraction project from scratch.

Comment: Look...osmand part you were looking at is a separate component. Of course you can create an external "library" project and use it from within your Android project, but you **cannot** create an Android project without a manifest.xml. If you want to modularize an app, it is perfectly fine to have different components that are somehow _platform independent_ and so you may reuse them within your Android and server-side logic.

Comment: But still Sir as a beginner...from where should i get the idea about how should i modularize my app and all...please suggest some links

Comment: Hmm, I guess the max 580 chars here are too few to explain. This is a whole topic which deals with software architectures etc. You should first of all ask yourself whether it is appropriate to modularize, especially whether it will give you any advantage, 'cause doing so will introduce additional complexity to your system.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a library not an application. As all application in android must have manifest.xml but libraries dont. The DataExtractionOSM in that project is a library just like any java library.

Check out the following [Create library for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708823/create-library-for-android-development)

Comment: Sir please suggest some from where i can learn how to create my library

Comment: Did you check the link I posted?