# Share library between projects

Tags: android, android-studio

I was looking in the Android studio help and didn't came up with anything that works.
lets say I'm developing 2 apps: app1 and app2. the 2 apps share common logic between them, so I have library lib1. In eclipse, I could have them all in the same workspace, and any change to lib1 (during work on either app1 or app2) would be nicely appear in the other one.

Android studio suggest to import the library into module. While "working", it doesn't apply any changes. The import actually copies the code, without any reference to the original. while this might be tolerable for stable libraries, this is an impossibility for developing a project group.
There is no way that copying and pasting code from the first copy to the second copy is what they intended. 
Is there a solution someone aware of?

Comment: 1. Create Android library 2. Add to your other modules(apps) dependencies `compile project(:mylib)`. 3. Profit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create library for Android development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708823/create-library-for-android-development)

Comment: JaredBurrows thanks, can't seems to find an option like this in studio (version 1.2.1.1)

Comment: Via IDE: `File -> New -> Module -> Android Library`. Via Gradle: add new module to `settings.gradle` and apply `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` to the configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I have done that, but I'm new to grade so I don't know how to share a library that is placed in another folder

Comment: Read me first comment and the duplicated link. You create the module and then add in to your dependencies.

Comment: Thank for all your help, but the link above does not seem to be referring to my issue (as far as I can see - I'm new to Android studio)... I'm not trying to share a compiled library, but an actual project/module so I'll be able to alter it and consume it from multiple locations. as far as what you put in the first line, compile project(':texterlibrary') seems to work when the module is imported to the current project. when this happens, it is useless as it's just copied (as I've mentioned). I don't know the command for compile project('some other location'). path didn't work there.

Comment: The link above needs to be updated with AndroidStudio/Intellij for the Gradle build system. What you are looking for is a tutorial.

Comment: What is the status of this?

Answer (score 0):

### Remote Library:

You still need to create an `Android Library` but you need to push it to a your local maven repository to use it locally or to an online repository like `Jcenter` or `OSS Sonatype`.

### Local Library:

```
Top Gradle Folder
.
+-- Lib-AndroidLibrary
|   +-- src
+-- App-MyApp1
|   +-- src
+-- App-MyApp2
|   +-- src
```

In `App-MyApp1` and `App-MyApp2`'s `build.gradle`, you will need:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Lib-AndroidLibrary')
}
```

Comment: As I don't have a local maven repo, I'll have to check if this works. 
can't git be used?
I do thank you for your effort. You spent a lot of time helping and it is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: These are your available options.

Comment: @donald Let me know how far you get, I can always help.

Comment: hope to get some info on gradle and give it a go during the weekend. wlyk. And thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Using a filesystem feature called 'junction' did the work for me. I put my .java files I wanted to share in a separate folder.

```
    Example: d:\Android\mylib\SharedClass.java
```

Then I stepped into the project directory d:\Andorid\ExampleApp\app\src\main\java\com\domain\ and executed this command-line command:

```
    mklink /J mylib d:\Android\mylib
```

This created a kind of a symbolic link (junction). After that, extra package appeared in my Android Studio project tree. One was com.domain.mylib, other one com.domain.exampleactivity
I also tried to use hard links (mklink /H), but it did not work. Android Studio is saving files through an intermediate file and renames it after writing is done, which wipes the hard link out.