# findViewById returning null inside a jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a small piece of code that works correctly in its own project (it is just a file selection dialog). I wanted to use it in my larger project, so I exported the FileSelector as a jar by doing the following:

- Right click on the FileSelector project and click 'Export'
- Select Java -> JAR file
- Set the 'export destination'
- Click 'Finish'
- Copy the exported .jar file into MyProject/libs
- Right click on MyProject -> Refresh
- Right click on MyProject -> Properties
- Click 'Java Build Path'
- In the 'Libraries' tab, click "Add JARs" and select the .jar file I just copied into MyProject

I was getting the error "Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: AndroidManifest.xml", so I just unselected AndroidManifest.xml from the list of files to export to the jar and created it again.

MyProject seems to build fine, but when I run it and click the button that should display the file selection dialog, I get a null pointer exception. I went back and tracked it down in the FileSelection code, and it is a simple

```
mFilterSpinner = (Spinner) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.fileFilter);
```

that is returning null. Is there something I have not done in the project setup that will allow a call like this to work from inside a jar? Or is there something wrong with my procedure for packaging up and importing the jar?

Comment: How do you inject `R.id.fileFilter` from the larger project into your JAR? How do you set the view context?

Comment: @his It did not do anything special. fileFilter is declared in an xml file in res/layout. The way it is referenced that works in the original project but not the jar is:

 private void prepareFilterSpinner(String[] fitlesFilter) 
 {
     
  mFilterSpinner = (Spinner) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.fileFilter);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Android UI components, I think you should be using it in another project as an Android library.

Comment: It is an Android UI component that is returning null. What do you mean by use it as an Android library?

Comment: U can't ship Android UI components in a jar AFAIK. That's the very reason ActionbarSherlock is an Android library as it has the UI elements. You can mark an Android project which wouldn't have a manifest but uses Android UI components as a library project and include it as a library in your other projects.

Comment: Some more information in this SO thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252552/differences-between-jar-android-library-and-android-library-project

Comment: So all I have to do is check "Is Library" in the FileSelector project and follow the same procedure of exporting the jar and it should work?

Comment: No, you mark your the present jar project as a library and add it as a library in your other project. More details in think link. http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: @Netin Sethi Ok that works. But to do it like this I have to explain to other developers that are working in this repository "You have to open this other project too at the same time otherwise you will get errors?" That seems awkward, no?

Comment: In the SO thread i shared, it is mentioned that one can't include resources folder in a jar. Try to do away with the jar using the method explained in http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Comment: That's the way it is to do such things as of now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Values in `R` class would be modified. So, you can't find your view when using compiled R inside your Jar.

The only solution is using android library project and reference resources and sources through it. Otherwise, you can referencing it by making your android library project into AAR archive.

Comment: What is an AAR archive (Google doesn't seem to know... :) ). Will this method let me use the resources without always having to have the library open in my workspace?

Comment: AAR stands for Android ARchive. Yes, if you archive library project into an AAR file, you can use library project just like an ordinary jar file. But I think it is in early development stage and you may use gradle build system. You can check it here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuild/article.html